# input causes EOF if program has piped stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import sys

piped_stdin = sys.stdin.read()
print(piped_stdin)
lucky_number = input('Enter your lucky number: ')
print(lucky_number)
```

```
% echo hi | python test.py
hi

Enter your lucky number: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    lucky_number = input('Enter your lucky number: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How can I use `input` after reading piped stdin?

`sys.stdin.read()` is not the culprit, `echo hi | python -c 'input(); input()'` has the same error as above, but above is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Do you really need to use `stdin` or a pipe? Why not `python test.py hi`, and get `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is more convenient in my case, I want to pass a lot of content via the clipboard or other variable command lines and piping to the program is easier on the fingers and brain to type than the `<(...)` file substitution alternative

Comment: You can pass a file **name**, too, then use `open(sys.argv[1]).read()`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think stdin might not even support the kind of usage this question asks for. You could post an answer with your alternative? It's at least what I'm doing right now, since our first two comments (thanks!)

Comment: I think the real issue here is that `.read()` will close the stdin buffer, but that doesn't explain why `input(); input()` fails

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` exhausts stdin, so there is nothing left for `input()` to read.